# Game status Live but page sharing forbidden?

Tags: facebook, live, status

I have submitted the game on Facebook (Ostrich Island), App center page says:
"App Detail Page Status: Live
Your app detail page is now live and will appear in Search."

BUT, I cannot even send the game link to my friend. When she receives it the message says the link was removed.
I have tried the different links:

http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=477037362322781
http://www.facebook.com/appcenter/ostrichisland

http://apps.facebook.com/ostrichisland

All of them works for me, but not for anybody else. 
Game Community page also shows Play Game button only for me.

Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you forget to take the app out of sandbox mode or is it demographically restricted?

Comment: It is not in Sandbox mode. App Detail Page Status: Live and there is two buttons now: "Web Preview" and "Cancel Submission". Also I have not defined any restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app's ID returns 'false' when accessed at https://graph.facebook.com/477037362322781

I'm almost sure, assuming you haven't deleted the app, that it's in sandbox mode

Check the 'Advanced' tab of settings, 3rd item:

[image: part of the advanced settings page]

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! It works now! So many settings, I completely forgot about that one.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is officially complaint by many Facebook users and now [Facebook game status](http://ifacebookstatus.com/category/games-facebook-status) is working well at my side.